# Python Dictionary in Robot Framwework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am parsing a list consisting of dictionaries Robot Framework.
Checked the type of the, while iterating the list, its showing as <class 'dict'> correctly. However, when I am trying to access the key; Robot is returning me as String indices must be integers.
Here is the snippet;

```
FOR  ${line}  IN  @{lines}
    ${type_string}=  evaluate  type(${line})
    log to console  ${type_string}
    log to console  ${line['note']}
END
```

log to console  ${line['note']} --> line isn't being considered as dictionary.

Comment: Is it possible you're hitting a non-dict list member, e.g. not all of them to be exclusively dictionaries?

Comment: can you share your dictionary? so we can have more information to evaluate this issue?

Comment: I have faced similar issue with Robot when attempting to access dictionaries generated by Python script. The fix for me was to remove all quotations from the key name - Does ``Log to Console    ${line[note]}`` work for you? See [Accessing individual dictionary items](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#accessing-list-and-dictionary-items)